# Connecting to oracle Database wouldn't work

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio, connection-string

I want to connect to Oracle Database by visual studio and populate datagridview by its data.  I know anything about Oracle . I just have SID,Username and password.
this is the code:

```
  using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var select = "SELECT * FROM tblProject";
         conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION="
         + "(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.3.50.205)(PORT=1521)))"
         + "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SID=sid)));"
         + "User Id=username;Password=pass;";

    }
    using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(conn.ConnectionString))
        {
            OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(select, connection);

            try
            {
                connection.Open();                    
                var ds = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(ds);
                dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
                dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }


        }
```

but the connection wouldn't open? where is the problem?
Thank you

Comment: what is the error message you getting?

Comment: @Niladri: Nothing. but when I check the connection.State it is closed

Comment: can you change `sid` to `SERVICE_NAME=sid` in your connection string? also try to open the connection before creating the adapter like `connection.Open(); `

Comment: what is `conn` here that you are using to declare the connection string like `conn.ConnectionString`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several DataConnectors on the market. At least from Microsoft, Oracle and DevArt. The connection strings are not fully compatible. So you have to pay attention when you are looking for examples.

I like to use ezconnect whenever it is possible:

username/password@[//]host[:port][/service_name]

less to type -> less errors. Once I had to connect to a test system which refused the old syntax, but accepted ezconnect. I never figured out why.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with the below code . Looks like you are using ODP.NET without the tnsnames.ora file using connect descriptor

```
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var select = "SELECT * FROM tblProject";
         conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION="
         + "(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.3.50.205)(PORT=1521)))"
         + "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=sid)));"
         + "User Id=username;Password=pass;";


    using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(conn.ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open(); 
            OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(select, connection);

            try
            {
                var ds = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(ds);
                dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
                dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }


        }

}
```

check this documentation at the "Using the connect descriptor" section 
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b28375/featConnecting.htm